# Request Parameter Versioning

Tags: rest, jersey, versioning

I am using Jersey to map the requests to a service class. I am trying to implement request parameter versioning to the application. The issue is Jersey only maps using URI and ignores the parameters. Also I want different request methods to be executed based only on the request parameter. For example, "http://www.example.com/content?version=1" should be directed to MethodA and "http://www.example.com/content?version=2" should be directed to MethodB. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is what you are trying to do, but it seems like you just want to read the parameters. You can get the parameters with Jersey, with the `@QueryParam` annotation. So for this URI:

```
yourBaseUri/content?version=1
```

An example would be:

```
@GET
@Path("/content")
public Response myMethod(@QueryParam(value = "version") String version) { 
    if("1".equals(version)) {
       // call MethodA
    } else if("2".equals(version))
       // call MethodB
    } else {
       // handle wrong/missing version number
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this possible using Annotations?

Comment: @SwethaRao Try my example and see if it works for you.

Comment: It works actually but I am trying to make this work only with annotations like it does in Spring. http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-versioning-for-rest-services

Comment: Well, this is how Jersey works. You need to use Spring if you want Spring annotations. And `@QueryParam` is an annotation by the way.